# Using CSV file for Azure Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, azure, csv, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to do a sentiment analysis on newspaper articles using Azure Cognitive Services (explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python))

It works perfectly fine for individual sentences, however, I'm struggling to get it to work for a csv file that contains list of quotes. I believe I'm doing something wrong when assigning the document, so the part with **

```
def sentiment_analysis_example(client):
**documents = ["I had the best day of my life. I wish you were there with me."]**
response = client.analyze_sentiment(documents=documents)[0]
print("Document Sentiment: {}".format(response.sentiment))
print("Overall scores: positive={0:.2f}; neutral={1:.2f}; negative={2:.2f} \n".format(
    response.confidence_scores.positive,
    response.confidence_scores.neutral,
    response.confidence_scores.negative,
))
for idx, sentence in enumerate(response.sentences):
    print("Sentence: {}".format(sentence.text))
    print("Sentence {} sentiment: {}".format(idx+1, sentence.sentiment))
    print("Sentence score:\nPositive={0:.2f}\nNeutral={1:.2f}\nNegative={2:.2f}\n".format(
        sentence.confidence_scores.positive,
        sentence.confidence_scores.neutral,
        sentence.confidence_scores.negative,
    ))        
sentiment_analysis_example(client)
```

I want to try a more efficient way rather than copy + pasting individual sentences into the "documents" section. I have tried creating a pandas data frame via

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/../Desktop/trial-sun.csv', sep=';')
```

However, when I make reference to this in `documents = []`, then I get an error saying

```
"TypeError: Mixing string and dictionary/object document input unsupported."
```

My guess is that what I'm passing on there needs to be of a different format but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

subscription_key = "<>"
headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key}
endpoint = "https://<>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
sentiment_url = endpoint + "/text/analytics/v3.0/sentiment"


def comment_sentiment(comment=None, cid=None):
    """
    Take a single comment in string and analyze the sentiment

    Args:
        comment --  The text content to analyze.
        cid -- The numeric id of the comment analyzed.
    """
    language = "en"
    try:
        document = {"id": cid, "language": language, "text": comment}
        body = {"documents": [document]}
        res = requests.post(sentiment_url,  headers=headers, json=body)
        data = res.json()
        # Extract key phrases
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))


def comment_summary(sentimentResult):
    """
        Take a single response data from comment_sentiment function and summarizes the result

        Args:
            sentimentResult --  The text response data to summarize.
    """

    summary = {"Id": 0, "Sentiment": "",
               "Positive": 0, "Neutral": 0, "Negative": 0}
    for document in sentimentResult['documents']:
        summary["Sentiment"] = document['sentiment'].capitalize()
        summary["Id"] = document['id']
        for each in document['sentences']:
            sentimentscore = each['sentiment']
            if sentimentscore == 'positive':
                summary["Positive"] += 1
            elif sentimentscore == 'negative':
                summary["Negative"] += 1
            else:
                summary["Neutral"] += 1
    return summary


def main(comment_df):
    """
    Take the data frame, get the sentiments and save the result to a CSV file

    Args:
        comment_df -- Data frame containing the text to analyze.
    Returns:
         A data frame consisting of the relevant columns
         'id','sentiment', 'positive','negative','neutral'.
    """
    df2 = comment_df
    # Drop any existing index and use a new one
    df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(u"Processing records in data frame....")
    for i, row in df2.iterrows():
        # print(u"Processing Record... #{}".format(i+1))
        text_data = df2.loc[i, "comment"].encode(
            "utf-8").decode("ascii", "ignore")
        sentimentResult = comment_sentiment(text_data, i+1)
        sentimentSummary = comment_summary(sentimentResult)
        # Add result to data frame
        df2.loc[i, "id"] = i+1
        df2.loc[i, "sentiment"] = sentimentSummary['Sentiment']
        df2.loc[i, "positive"] = sentimentSummary['Positive']
        df2.loc[i, "negative"] = sentimentSummary['Negative']
        df2.loc[i, "neutral"] = sentimentSummary['Neutral']
        dfx = df2[['id', 'sentiment', 'positive', 'negative', 'neutral']]
    print(u"Processing completed....")
    # Ensure that numbers are represented as integers and not float
    convert_dict = {'id': int,
                    'positive': int,
                    'negative': int,
                    'neutral': int,
                    'sentiment': str
                    }

    dfx = dfx.astype(convert_dict)
    return dfx


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # read comment data from csv
    commentData = pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JimXu199545/data/main/comment.csv", header=0, names=["comment"])
    commentData['nwords'] = commentData.comment.apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
    commentData['hashed'] = commentData.comment.apply(
        lambda x: hash("".join(x.split())))

    # Remove duplicated record but keep the first occurence of the record
    commentData.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
    # Reindex the data frame to prevent gaps in the indexes
    commentData.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df = main(commentData)
    df.to_csv('d:\\result.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Also, please refer these following links for more information:
[Reference1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/language-detection/overview#analyze-sentiment) , [Reference2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/overview?tabs=version-3)

Comment: Thank you for your answer though it does not quite help me with my issue it seems. Your code as well as mine works for individual comments (in string). My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to pass a whole document (consisting of various comments) into the part where I define documents